# How do I chain database queries with Promises in Node?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to chain a series of database queries in Node.js using the mysql2 module.

First of all, I will be moving to async/await, but I want to understand this method before doing that. I'm trying to understand promises in greater detail before using what I understand is syntactic sugar for them.

Here's my code:

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: 'phones'
});

console.log(pool);

pool.getConnection((connection) => {
    console.log('entered connection');
    connection.promise().query('select * from lists')
        .then(([rows, fields]) => {
            const lists = rows;
            return connection.promise().query('select * from numbers')
        }).then(([rows, fields]) => {
            const numbers = rows;
            return numbers;
        }).then(() => {
            console.log(lists);
            console.log(numbers);
            return lists;
        }).catch((error) => {
            throw error;
        }).finally(() => {
            connection.end();
        });
});

console.log('end');
```

And here's the output:

```
PromisePool {
...
}
end
```

The program just waits there and doesn't exit until I hit Ctrl-C. I understand enough to know that there's a promise that's awaiting resolution, but I don't understand why. Shouldn't I at least get the `entered connection` log? I'm not.

Comment: if you're using `then()` chaining, remember to _return something_ so that the next "then" handler has something to work with. If you're using arrow functions, remember that only bare arrow functions return (e.g. `() => 3` returns the value 3) - arrow functions with a function block _do not return anything_ unless you explicitly add a return statement (e.g. `() => { 3; }` does not return anything, that has to be `() => { return 3; }` to return 3)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, what I'm taking away from that is that each of the `then` calls should return something, but I added return values to each of my `then` calls and the behavior didn't change. Is the `pool.getConnection` being called? If so, why isn't the fist line in it outputing to the log?

Comment: your code shows no returns.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I had added them to my file. But it doesn't change anything. I've now added them to the sample code above. The output remains the same and the execution doesn't exit.

Comment: can you add await here - "const pool = await mysql.createPool({ " and check if the pool.getConnection is getting called or not. Also add a error field to the callback function of pool.getConnection and check if there is any error or not.